# select records having string with single quote -informix

Tags: informix

Hey I want to select records with name O'Neil, How can i do that in Informix.

select * from name_table where lastname = 'O'Neil' --> Doesn't Work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape single quote with another single quote:

```
select * from name_table where lastname = 'O''Neil';
```

Answer (score 0):

With Informix, you generally have two choices.

The Standard SQL technique ([described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768742/select-records-having-string-with-single-quote-informix/9771237#9771237) by [Michal Niklas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22595/michal-niklas)) always works and is the simple, recommended solution. All appearances of a single quote in a string are doubled up:

```
 SELECT * FROM Name_Table WHERE LastName = 'O'Neill';
```

An alternative technique that works unless you have set DELIMIDENT in your environment is to use double quotes around the string:

```
SELECT * FROM Name_Table WHERE LastName = "O'Neill";
```

If delimited identifiers are enabled by DELIMIDENT, then this has a different meaning; the DBMS will be looking for a column called "O'Neill" in the table (because it is an identifier, not a string).

If you have both quotes in a string, then you have to be be careful:

```
SELECT * FROM QuoteTable WHERE Quote = 'He said, "Don''t"!';
SELECT * FROM QuoteTable WHERE Quote = "He said, ""Don't""!';
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2nd answer with proposition of technology change.

I don't know what technology you use, but maybe you can use PreparedStatements. Example in Jython (Python that can use JDBC drivers):

```
db = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc_url, usr, passwd)
pstm = db.prepareStatement("select * from name_table where lastname=?")
pstm.setString(1, "O'Neil")
rs = pstm.executeQuery()
while (rs.next()):
    print('[%s]' % (rs.getString(1)))
```

As you see PreparedStatement use `?` as a placeholder and then you must fill it using `setString()` method. It is very useful if you have to do many similar selects, inserts etc. Have a look at Java6 documentation for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Similar techniques can be user for ODBC or other technologies.